# c# Requested registry access is not allowed even if i gave permission to Everyone

Tags: c#, permissions, remote-access, securityexception

I am reading a registry key on a remote computer like this :

```
RegistryKey regKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, pc1, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\NetworkTP_DB");
```

I went to the remote compute and i gave Full Control to Everyone and i still get :

> SecurityException was unhandled Requested registry access is not allowed.

I even turn off all firewall on that remote computer to make sure it doesn't affect anything, and now i really don't know what to do.

Any idea please ?

Comment: You need to escalate the privliages of the application in order to write to the registry and/or change the privliages of the user to allow them to do this.

Comment: What is that, Escalate the privilages of the application. I just want to read a key in LOCAL_MACHINE.